# Has_phone_number column does not exist

Tags: android

I am new to android and creating an application to print phone nos of contacts.
If a take the Uri as

```
Uri u=Uri.parse("content://contacts/people");
```

I am getting error in

```
ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER
```

field. If i try to get its index it comes -1.

If a use Uri

```
Uri u=ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI
```

I am able to get the above field.
Is there any difference between these two uri's.

thanks
tejinder

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any difference between these two uri's.

Absolutely. `content://contacts/people` is the old `Contacts` provider, not `ContactsContract`. Unless you are supporting Android 1.x devices, please use `ContactsContract`.

Comment: thanks but does that mean that they use database with different fields

Comment: @tejinder: Absolutely. Unless you are supporting Android 1.x devices, please use `ContactsContract`.

Comment: appreciate your quick response